# Wordpress custom widget that allows html codes

Tags: html, wordpress, widget

I just need a widget with a textarea where I can paste an embed code. Right now, whenever I save the widget, it auto removes the html codes.

```
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'embed' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Embed:' ); ?></label> 
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'embed' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'embed' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $embed ); ?>" />
```

It should work like the default text-widget where it runs HTML. Any way I can put a certain code to retain and run the HTML in my custom widget?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the default textwidget, it will serve your purposes.